# Whenever I add more than one row of data in my table, I get the error ''Getting unknown property"

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I am very new to yii2. I have 3 tables task, activties and employees. Whenever I add more than one row of data in Activity table I get the following error -

> "Getting unknown property: backend\models\Employee::Employee_ID"

My Activty model has these two get relation functions :

```
public function getTask()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Tasks::className(), ['Task_ID' => 'Task_ID']);
}

public function getEmployee()
{
     return $this->hasOne(Employee::className(), ['Employee_ID' => 'Employee_ID']);
}
```

In my _columns.php I am using the following to get the employee name in the gridview. But even when I comment this I get the error if I have more than one row in the Activity table.

```
 [
     'attribute' => 'Employee_ID', 
     'value' => 'employee.employee_name',
 ],
```

Can someone please help me understand why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Thank you

EDIT:

Added the Controller

`

```
class ActivitiesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
                'access'=>[
                'class'=>AccessControl::classname(),
                'only'=>['create','update'],
                'rules'=>[
                [
                        'allow'=>true,
                        'roles'=>['@']
                         ],
                         ]
                    ],

            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                    'bulk-delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Activity models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {    
        $searchModel = new ActivitiesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * Displays a single Activity model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {   
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        if($request->isAjax){
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return [
                    'title'=> "Activity #".$id,
                    'content'=>$this->renderAjax('view', [
                        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                    ]),
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                            Html::a('Edit',['update','id'=>$id],['class'=>'btn btn-primary','role'=>'modal-remote'])
                ];    
        }else{
            return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Activity model.
     * For ajax request will return json object
     * and for non-ajax request if creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $model = new Activity();  

        if($request->isAjax){
            /*
            *   Process for ajax request
            */
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            if($request->isGet){
                return [
                    'title'=> "Create new Activity",
                    'content'=>$this->renderAjax('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                                Html::button('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>"submit"])

                ];         
            }else if($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()){
                return [
                    'forceReload'=>'#crud-datatable-pjax',
                    'title'=> "Create new Activity",
                    'content'=>'<span class="text-success">Create Activity success</span>',
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                            Html::a('Create More',['create'],['class'=>'btn btn-primary','role'=>'modal-remote'])

                ];         
            }else{           
                return [
                    'title'=> "Create new Activity",
                    'content'=>$this->renderAjax('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                                Html::button('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>"submit"])

                ];         
            }
        }else{
            /*
            *   Process for non-ajax request
            */
            if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Activity_ID]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Activity model.
     * For ajax request will return json object
     * and for non-ajax request if update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $model = $this->findModel($id);       

        if($request->isAjax){
            /*
            *   Process for ajax request
            */
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            if($request->isGet){
                return [
                    'title'=> "Update Activity #".$id,
                    'content'=>$this->renderAjax('update', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                                Html::button('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>"submit"])
                ];         
            }else if($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()){
                return [
                    'forceReload'=>'#crud-datatable-pjax',
                    'title'=> "Activity #".$id,
                    'content'=>$this->renderAjax('view', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                            Html::a('Edit',['update','id'=>$id],['class'=>'btn btn-primary','role'=>'modal-remote'])
                ];    
            }else{
                 return [
                    'title'=> "Update Activity #".$id,
                    'content'=>$this->renderAjax('update', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]),
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                                Html::button('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>"submit"])
                ];        
            }
        }else{
            /*
            *   Process for non-ajax request
            */
            if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Activity_ID]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('update', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete an existing Activity model.
     * For ajax request will return json object
     * and for non-ajax request if deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        if($request->isAjax){
            /*
            *   Process for ajax request
            */
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ['forceClose'=>true,'forceReload'=>'#crud-datatable-pjax'];
        }else{
            /*
            *   Process for non-ajax request
            */
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }


    }

     /**
     * Delete multiple existing Activity model.
     * For ajax request will return json object
     * and for non-ajax request if deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionBulkDelete()
    {        
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $pks = explode(',', $request->post( 'pks' )); // Array or selected records primary keys
        foreach ( $pks as $pk ) {
            $model = $this->findModel($pk);
            $model->delete();
        }

        if($request->isAjax){
            /*
            *   Process for ajax request
            */
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ['forceClose'=>true,'forceReload'=>'#crud-datatable-pjax'];
        }else{
            /*
            *   Process for non-ajax request
            */
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Finds the Activity model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Activity the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Activity::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

`

The index.php below

`

```
<div class="activity-index">
    <div id="ajaxCrudDatatable">
        <?=GridView::widget([
            'id'=>'crud-datatable',
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'pjax'=>true,
            'columns' => require(__DIR__.'/_columns.php'),
            'toolbar'=> [
                ['content'=>
                    Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>', ['create'],
                    ['role'=>'modal-remote','title'=> 'Create new Activities','class'=>'btn btn-default']).
                    Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>', [''],
                    ['data-pjax'=>1, 'class'=>'btn btn-default', 'title'=>'Reset Grid']).
                    '{toggleData}'.
                    '{export}'
                ],
            ],          
            'striped' => true,
            'condensed' => true,
            'responsive' => true,          
            'panel' => [
                'type' => 'primary', 
                'heading' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Activities listing',
                'before'=>'<em>* Resize table columns just like a spreadsheet by dragging the column edges.</em>',
                'after'=>BulkButtonWidget::widget([
                            'buttons'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>&nbsp; Delete All',
                                ["bulk-delete"] ,
                                [
                                    "class"=>"btn btn-danger btn-xs",
                                    'role'=>'modal-remote-bulk',
                                    'data-confirm'=>false, 'data-method'=>false,// for overide yii data api
                                    'data-request-method'=>'post',
                                    'data-confirm-title'=>'Are you sure?',
                                    'data-confirm-message'=>'Are you sure want to delete this item'
                                ]),
                        ]).                        
                        '<div class="clearfix"></div>',
            ]
        ])?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php Modal::begin([
    "id"=>"ajaxCrudModal",
    "footer"=>"",// always need it for jquery plugin
])?>
<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

`

The view.php below

```
`

<div class="activity-view">

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'Activity_ID',
            'Activity_name',
            'Activity_description',
            'Due_Date',
            'Status',
            'Task_ID',
          //  'Employee_ID',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

`

The table schema is below

ActivityTbl

```
Field                Type      Null     Key     Default     Extra   
Activity_ID         int(11)     NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment
Activity_name     varchar(100)  NO      NULL    
Activity_description varchar(255)   NO      NULL    
Due_Date            date        NO      NULL    
Status  enum('Open','Completed','Closed')   NO      NULL    
Task_ID            int(11)     NO       NULL    
Employee_ID        int(11)     NO       NULL
```

Employee table

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra   
employee_ID     int(11)     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
employee_name   varchar(150)    NO      NULL
```

Comment: Please, update your question with Employee and Activty table schemes

Comment: show the controller/action, model   and view related code please

Comment: I have added the model, view index and the activity table schemes as asked.

Comment: Naming of columns seems pretty inconsistent. I would suggest using only lower case letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Activity` table you have `Employee_ID`, meanwhile in the `Employee` table the corresponding field is named `employee_ID`. Pay attention to the first letter case ;)

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you! So to rectify the issue I can just make change to the table and create the model again for employee? Or will I have to make any changes in the code?

Comment: Yes, it will be enough. Try to rename the column and check the application first. If the app does not work - try to re-generate the model

Comment: Alright thanks SilverFire! I will do as said and select the answer :)

Comment: Yes renaming the column and making small changes in the other pages made the difference!! Thank you for the help!!